# implementing command change from sbt documentation

Tags: scala, sbt

I am reading the [sbt documentation on commands](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html). It talks about how one can write commands by creating a commandExample and placing it in the project directory and creating command word sequences in the build.sbt.

My implementation follows that instructions and the commands for hello and helloAll both work ,  however the changeColor command throws an error. What imput parameter am I to enter in to the sbt terminal to activate the newly made command ?

Comment: What did you try? What's the error you get? I think "color fg blue" should work.

Comment: well to activate the other methods I typed in the name of the method. So hello in the sbt terminal returned Hi! . I tried adding in changeColor by itself and with a number of varied follow ons , but it throws an error. Edit: Just tried that input there works - I found the instructions on implementation  a little unclear. thanks